# Can I legally compell a student to go back to their home country?

Tags: united-states, visa, state-university

Suppose that I am the owner of a fully-owned private company in the USA. I am providing a full scholarship to a student from country X to go to the USA to do a 4-year PhD.

Can I add a clause to the scholarship contract that says that the student must go back to country X after finishing the PhD and will have to take a full-time job and work there for at least two years before re-entering the USA?

Is this clause enforceable from my position?

**N.B.** If they breach the clause by getting a job in the USA, they have to repay the scholarship amount.

Comment: Nobody can guarantee that they will get an academic full-time job.

Comment: What's the point? They'll breach the clause, get a job in the US and repay you the scholarship.

Comment: @Roland my understanding of the question is that the student wouldn't necessarily breach the contract simply by not getting a job, but would not be allowed to re-enter the US.

Comment: @greendrake What's the point of asking what's the point? It's a hypothetical question about how the law works, not an announcement of foolproof plan.

Comment: @bdb484 Because if the plan is not legally foolproof, the answer is "you can't force them".

Comment: @Greendrake, *They'll breach the clause, get a job in the US and repay you the scholarship.* --- I don't have a problem with that.

Comment: @Someone the only one that is allowed to determine who can and can't enter the US as a non citizen is the **federal foreign office**

Comment: @Roland, *Nobody can guarantee that they will get an academic full-time job.* --- I changed it to a plain job.

Comment: OP's scenario is commonly implemented as loan forgiveness programs: we will loan you tuition, and if you go work in some position ([charitable](https://www.peacecorps.gov/volunteer/benefits/student-loan-information/), [education](https://studentaid.gov/manage-loans/forgiveness-cancellation/teacher), [underserved community](https://www.ihs.gov/loanrepayment/), [government](https://sfs.opm.gov/)) for n years after, we will forgive your loan. If not, original loan repayment conditions stand.

Comment: @user71659: Most commonly, it's a company paying for training or education but requiring a committment to recoup their investment.  OP's scenario is especially weird in that in his scenario, a US company is providing US training but then ordering the recipient to leave the US.  This makes very little sense to me.

Comment: @Brian Quasi-charity: we sponsor somebody from $poorcountry if they go back and presumably make a positive change. The US government, often in collaboration with sponsoring foreign governments, has the same idea with J-1 visas that [block the visitor](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/study/exchange/waiver-of-the-exchange-visitor/eligibility.html) from work or immigrant status until they return home for 2 years.

Comment: @user71659: I think the motivations of the organization offering the scholarship is relevant to its enforcability.  And I'll note that this is a rather common problem for such scholarships: An organization funds someone's education in the hopes of improving local interests, but the student then gets employed in the US, rendering the scholarship's investment wasted.

Comment: @user366312: You *should* have a problem with Greendrake's scenario.  That scenario will only apply to the students who succeed in obtaining their green card, which will disportionately apply to the better students.

Comment: @user71659 but that is **the government**, which can do visa, not some other organisation that can not.

Comment: @Trish I never said a company had visa powers, I said the "idea," the motivation is similar.

Comment: @Greendrake Even if it's legally foolproof, you can't necessarily force them because they can ignore a court order or hide from enforcement authorities. I don't see what the use is in raising these kinds of points, other than feigning superior knowledge to obscure a commenter's inability to answer the actual question.

Comment: @bdb484 "Force" in this context means only one thing — "legally compel". I don't see what the use is in picking on a reasonable question, other than to childishly entertain hubristic pride.

Comment: It sounds like we've reached an agreement.

Answer (score 10):

### Such a clause is probably unenforceable

First, it’s borderline [unconscionable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscionability), “extremely unjust, or overwhelmingly one-sided in favor of the party who has the superior bargaining power, that they are contrary to good conscience.” If such an argument can be made out, the clause is void.

Notwithstanding, it’s a [restraint of trade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restraint_of_trade) clause and these are only valid to the extent that they legitimately protect the company’s interest. They are subject to strict time, geographic, and industry constraints - a blanket ban for 2 years over the entire US in all industries (as written, the guy can’t work as a barista) is clearly too broad. The clause would have to be narrowed to a much shorter time (say 6 months), only cover geographic areas where the company operated, and only restrict work that directly competes with the company.

Finally, it’s a penalty clause - the amount of damages required to be paid (the entire scholarship) is not a genuine pre-estimate of the damage the company will suffer if the term is breached. Such clauses are unenforceable as only governments are allowed punitive sanctions.

Comment: Accompanying training with a required work commitment is rather common, though typically the commitment is *more* restrictive than that proposed by OP (i.e., the recipient must either work for that company or repay the loan): Repaying the scholarship is a genuine estimate of the damage the company will suffer, because that's how much money the company spend with no reward. Why is OP's proposed contract less enfofrceable than similar committments commonly applied by US companies who pay for employee training?

Comment: @Brian because OPs contract seems to bar someone from staying in the country they just spent years in to study and does not even offer them work in their home country.

Comment: @Trish: Excellent point in regards to guaranteed employement.

Comment: Unconscionable? That's actually what many J-1 visa holders are forced to do by law per INA 212(e). The penalty is different, though, they just can't get many of the other non-immigrant or immigrant visas, they don't have to pay back the scholarship.

Comment: Note that in some countries, people pursuing some studies (which are basically free) have an obligation to either work for the state for a number of years or pay back some amount which is considered the cost of the studies. Basically the same idea.

Comment: "Basically the same idea": not at all, in the question no job is provided at all, neither in the US nor in the home country.

Comment: @Brian The student fulfilled 4 years of their contract by studying for a PhD; there has not been a total and utter failure of consideration, so they are entitled to payment. The full amount of the contract is not a genuine pre-estimate because the company got some of what they paid for, and there has been no attempt to quantify the damage suffered if the student stays in the country.

Comment: @DaleM I don't know how the law works precisely but it sounds defensible that the student did not partially fulfill the contract, in the same sense that if I pay you $5 to go to the shops and buy me some milk, and you go to the shops, buy milk, and consume it entirely yourself, you can't then tell me you've done half the job and should get half the pay.

Comment: @BenMillwood yes, you don’t understand how the law works. The starting point is that if I do any part of the contract, I’m entitled to payment (unless it’s an entire contract like building a house but this isn’t that). If I break the contract and that causes you harm, I’m liable to pay damages for that harm. For example, if I sell you a 10 day cruise in the South Pacific and the ship sinks on day 6, you are entitled to damages but you are not entitled to a refund because I performed some of the contract (actual case here).